# JS scroll after delay

Tags: javascript, scroll, delay, smoothing

I'm trying to make my website scroll to specific post that is on separate page. I figured the PHP part behind this to generate anchors for me however I'm stuck with JS part. I managed to make webpage start at position 0,0 and then to go to static anchor tag. What I struggle with is how do I make JS fetch anchor tag from current URL and then make it smoothly scroll to given tag after short delay.

My current code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (location.hash) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
      }
});

setTimeout("window.location.hash = '#scroll';", 5000);
```

I found following snipped that fetches an anchor tag off URL but I'm not sure how can I make it execute after some delay.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      function filterPath(string) {
      return string
        .replace(/^\//,'')
        .replace(/(index|default).[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/,'')
        .replace(/\/$/,'');
      }
      var locationPath = filterPath(location.pathname);
      var scrollElem = scrollableElement('html', 'body');

      $('a[href*=#]').each(function() {
        var thisPath = filterPath(this.pathname) || locationPath;
        if (  locationPath == thisPath
        && (location.hostname == this.hostname || !this.hostname)
        && this.hash.replace(/#/,'') ) {
          var $target = $(this.hash), target = this.hash;
          if (target) {
            var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;
            $(this).click(function(event) {
              event.preventDefault();
              $(scrollElem).animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 400, function() {
                location.hash = target;
              });
            });
          }
        }
      });

      // use the first element that is "scrollable"
      function scrollableElement(els) {
        for (var i = 0, argLength = arguments.length; i <argLength; i++) {
          var el = arguments[i],
              $scrollElement = $(el);
          if ($scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0) {
            return el;
          } else {
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(1);
            var isScrollable = $scrollElement.scrollTop()> 0;
            $scrollElement.scrollTop(0);
            if (isScrollable) {
              return el;
            }
          }
        }
        return [];
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem using snippet that I found on [CSS-Tricks forum](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/70154/#Comment_70154). It scrolls to an anchor tag on page load, always starting from the very top of the page.

```
$(window).bind("ready", function() {
   var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$('a[href="#'+urlHash+'"]').offset().top}, 1500);        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe setTimeout accepts any old code passed as a string, only function names. Try using an anonymous function instead:

`setTimeout(function() { window.location.hash = '#scroll'; }, 5000);`

Comment: Passing a string to setTimeout/Interval is valid and works, it's just not good practice. `setTimeout("alert('Hello!')", 1000);`

Comment: oh, weird. javascript is weird.

Comment: The code I have at the moment works in fact, so does yours. I'm trying however to achieve a smooth scrolling effect, and mainly because my JS knowledge is quite limited I just don't know how to connect two snippets, that I noted earlier, together.